# Save relevant portion of URL in Perl

Tags: perl

I'm doing the following to save the relevant portion of a URL to a Perl variable:

```
($url) = $url =~ m! (.+?\w) (?: /|\z) !x;
($url) = $url =~ /\/\/(.*)/;
```

I'm trying to save everything between "http(s|)://" and the next "/".  Is there a better way to do this on a single line?

Comment: What do you want for `http://host:8080/`?

Comment: I suppose I want the port included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URI.pm is nice, but you don't always need the overhead.

```
my ($host_port) = $uri =~ m{ ^ https? :// ([^/]*) }xi;
```

Or if you just want the host,

```
my ($host) = $uri =~ m{ ^ https? :// ([^/:]*) }xi;
```

Answer (score 4):

use [`URI`](https://metacpan.org/pod/URI)

```
use URI;

my $uri = URI->new('http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions');
say $uri->host;
say $uri->host_port;
```

Outputs:

```
www.stackoverflow.com
www.stackoverflow.com:80
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this regex: `:\/\/([^\/]+)\/`

Example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$url = 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/';
$url =~ /:\/\/([^\/]+)\//;
print $1."\n";
```

Comment: Note: This will give the wrong result if the URI isn't of the correct form.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work but it was likely something I'm doing wrong.